MongoDB trying to get information from Local instead of Atlas
I'm currently creating a website, and on the backend I am using MongoDB Atlas to store user / token information.
I have functions to create accounts and issue them tokens however while I was trying to create an authenticate token function I'm running into an odd issue. On the first line of the function I'm grabbing a token from the database which runs fine and grabs it from the database. But the next thing the function tries to do is get the expiry date. However, whenever I try and grab the expiry date (or any of the actual information inside the document, I tested this with other collections and documents with different keys and stuff), MongoDB tries to grab it from a localhost rather than Atlas. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I'll leave my code below.
 def authorize_token(database, token):
    token_document = db["tokens"].find({"token": token})[0] # .to_list() # .next()
    
    if token_document:
        if token_document["expiry"] <= time.time():
            print("expired")
            return 410, "Expired Token"
        
        print("past expiry")

        return 200, token_document["id"]
    else:
        return 400, "No Token"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = MongoClient(getenv("MONGO_DB_URI"))["BetterMUN"]
    if db["users"].find({"username": "oliver"}):
        print("proof working")
    authorize_token(db, "5a4303cd-fe36-40f1-be34-6dc843dbd99b")


The find() method in MongoDB returns a cursor, not a list or a single document. When you attempt to index ([0]) into it directly, it might behave inconsistently, especially if the result set is empty or if you're accessing fields lazily.
You should use the find_one method instead, which directly retrieves a single document matching the query without returning a cursor.

I use try and except blocks, because if the output of the find function is an empty array, and if I try to get the [0] out of emptiness, it just raises an error. And I use try and except with [0] while authenticating.
I hope it solves the problem. If it doesn't please add the error output.
